# How to resolve data append in factorygirl while testing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am new to rails. i try to write test for a model for that i use factory-girl gem. In that data was taken from XML file.

My problem is when ever am running my rspec file, data was appended every time, in XML file i have only 32 data, but every time am executing rsepc data was increasing...

i even tried database_cleaner but same result.

I want to delete the data in factory-girl.

is there anyway to avoid duplication in factory-girl?

is there anyway to use where condition like query for factory-girl?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The following things use to reset **factory girl** data.

Add following line in your **Gemfile** and try bundle install.

```
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.8.0", :group => :test
```

**In spec_helper.rb:**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Other things

  # Clean up the database
  require 'database_cleaner'
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.orm = "mongoid"
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```